# Posting data using Ajax to Razor page in .netcore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Firstly, Is it possible to post data to the .netcore 2.0 pages using ajax?

Secondly, Is Razor pages(.Netcore 2.0) substitute for the MVC approach? Alternate approach?

```
$('#sum').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',

        url: '/Manifest/Sum/3/5',
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Succes y'all");
        }
    });
});

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly CloudSolution.Models.DomainData.ManifestContext _context;

    public IndexModel(CloudSolution.Models.DomainData.ManifestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<ManifestViewModel> ManifestViewModel { get;set; }
    public IActionResult HelloAjax()
    {
        return Content("Hello from the controller!", "text/plain");
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("/Manifest/Sum/{firstNumber}/{secondNumber}")]
    public IActionResult Sum(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        return Content((firstNumber + secondNumber).ToString(), "text/plain");
    }
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        ManifestViewModel = await _context.ManifestViewModel.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you're having? And no, correct me if I'm wrong .NET Core 2.0 is using MVC 6 Razor syntax... Not a substitute

Comment: When I post data to an MVC controller the data comes through to my Controller Method but when I tried it using .netcore 2.0 razor pages the method does not get called.

Comment: I am not sure if the `Route` attribute is supported yet... it seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6605).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are multiple options here:

Use handlers in your Razor Pages, see docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page

or Use MVC pattern for Ajax(ish) kind of calls and configure middleware to have all Controller results to look in the "Pages" folder instead of the "Views" folder so you can keep all .cshtml together.

or Use another Javascript framework to handle more complex pages.

Second, Razor Pages (MVVM) is not a substitute. You can choose to use either, or even both together.

All in all i think that page handlers are most interesting to give try,
Took a look at this article, specifically the section titled: "Using Multiple GET or POST Actions via Handlers":
https://stackify.com/asp-net-razor-pages-vs-mvc/

Comment: does handlers only work with forms submit buttons? what i am aiming to achieve is a drop and drop functionality without the page refreshing.

Comment: Depending on what you exactly want your clientside to behave after the post depends on how you could construct the functionality. How far we could go using handlers is not clear to me yet. What i do know is that .net will always render your HTML serverside, which means that without clientside DOM manipulation this will result in a page refresh. So i think you will always want some kind of javascript to "complete" the Drag and Drop functionality.

Answer (score 1):

2 choices.

1) Try adding a Api controller.  Super easy. 
2 ) Try using page handler example OnPostAjax() and you link will be something like index/?handler=ajax